# "like" search and highlighting in PHP

Tags: php, search, highlighting

I have list of brands and want to provide a search function with highlighting. For example, there are the following brands

- Apple
- Cewe Color
- L'Oréal
- Microsoft
- McDonald's
- Tom Tailor

The user then types `lor` in search form. I'm using the following snippet for searching

```
class search {
  private function simplify($str) {
    return str_replace(array('&',' ',',','.','?','|','\'','"'), '', iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str));
  }
  public function do_search($search) {
    $search = self::simplify($search);
    $found = array();
    foreach (self::$_brands as $brand) {
      if (mb_strstr(self::simplify($brand['name']), $search) !== false) $found[]= $brand;
    }
    return $found;
  }
}
```

That gives me:

- Cewe Color
- L'Oréal
- Tom Tailor

How would be a highlighting possible? Like:

- `Cewe Co<b>lor</b>`
- `L'<b>Oré</b>al`
- `Tom Tai<b>lor</b>`

Btw: I know, that most things can be done with `str_replace()`, but that fit my needs not in all cases

Comment: I can think of one solution but it is probably inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self::$_brands` contains result from database (containing columns `name`, `name_lower`, `name_translit`, `name_simplified`)

```
class search {
    private function translit($str) {
        return iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', str_replace(array('ä', 'ü', 'ö', 'ß'), array('a', 'u', 'o', 's'), mb_strtolower($str)));
    }

    private function simplify($str) {
        return preg_replace('/([^a-z0-9])/ui', '', self::translit($str));
    }

    public function do_search($simplified) {
        $found = array();
        foreach (self::$_brands as $brand) {
            if (mb_strstr($brand['name_simplified'], $simplified) !== false) $found[]= $brand;
        }
        return $found;
    }

    private function actionDefault() {
        $search = $_POST['search_fld'];
        $simplified = self::simplify($search);
        $result = self::do_search($simplified);
        $brands = array();
        foreach ($result as $brand) {
            $hl_start = mb_strpos($brand['name_simplified'], $simplified);
            $hl_len = mb_strlen($simplified);
            $brand_len = mb_strlen($brand['name']);
            $tmp = '';
            $cnt_extra = 0;
            $start_tag = false;
            $end_tag = false;
            for ($i = 0; $i < $brand_len; $i++) {
                if (($i - $cnt_extra) < mb_strlen($brand['name_simplified']) && mb_substr($brand['name_translit'], $i, 1) != mb_substr($brand['name_simplified'], $i - $cnt_extra, 1)) $cnt_extra++;
                if (($i - $cnt_extra) == $hl_start && !$start_tag) {
                    $tmp .= '<b>';
                    $start_tag = true;
                }
                $tmp .= mb_substr($brand['name'], $i, 1);
                if (($i - $cnt_extra + 1) == ($hl_start + $hl_len) && !$end_tag) {
                    $tmp .= '</b>';
                    $end_tag = true;
                }
            }
            if ($start_tag && !$end_tag) $tmp .= '</b>';
            $brands[] = "<a href=\"/brand/" . rawurlencode($brand['name']) . "\">" . $tmp . "</a>";
        }
        echo implode(' | ', $brands);
    }
}
```

Comment: tried that already :) check out my updated answer, it should work with much less code ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
$highlighted = str_replace($search, "<b>$search</b>", $brand);
```

would be the simplest method.

Answer (score 1):

:)

[image]

Works with FedEx also ;)

[image]

```
$_brands = array
(
"Apple",
"Cewe Color",
"L'Oréal",
"Microsoft",
"McDonald's",
"Tom Tailor"
);

$q = 'lor';
$search = clean($q);

foreach($_brands as $key => $brand){
    $brand = clean($brand);
    $x = stripos($brand, $search);
    if($x !== false){

        $regexp = NULL;
        $l = strlen($q);

        for($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++){
            $regexp .= mb_strtoupper($q[$i]).'.?';
        }
        $regexp = substr($regexp, 0, strlen($regexp) - 2);

        $new = $_brands[$key];
        $new = preg_replace('#('.$regexp.')#ui', '<b>$0</b>', $new);
        echo $new."<br />";

    }

}

function clean($string){
    $string = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('#[^\w]#ui', '', $string);
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: I did already thought about something like that. I'll tune this a bit (I think one could use `str_replace` instead of `preg_replace` in the `foreach` loop. But that would help me. I'll post my solution when it's finished.

Comment: @rabudde, I am close to solving this but my lack of knowledge in regex isn't helping :) One could write regex to replace 'lor' and every character in between.

Comment: Hum, this should work, but the `ucwords()` doesn't fit brands like FedEx or 'ABC News'

Comment: @rabudde, I tweaked code a little bit, works now. ucwords() is redundant now.

Comment: hey, your work is getting better! great! but there's another case: try to search 'ab' with your function on brand 'Paco Rabanne' (it's going to highlight `P<b>aco Rab</b>anne` instead of `Paco R<b>ab</b>anne`

Comment: @rabudde, I see :) OK, you have new regexp in my answer, take a test now.

Comment: I can't test it right, but I can see you made the ungreedy `(.*)` to fit only char by `.`?

Comment: @rabudde, `.*` is greedy, `.*?` is ungreedy, `.?` matches any char 0 or 1 time, here is the paste, it should work... http://ideone.com/Cf9Pl

Comment: I'm glad to see your enthusiasm and I really don't like to say that and I don't want to annoy you, but there are many more cases. I.e. if you search for 'nh' in 'Benson & Hedges'. It's hard to find a correct regex. Your expression `.?` should be something like this `[::all-chars-except-these-in-$q::]*`

Comment: At the moment I'm still using my solution, because its highlighting is better. I can highlight all addressed cases: 'Benson & Hedges', 'Paco Rabanne', 'L'Oréal'. For sure your solution highlights all matches of a search (i.e. 'an' in 'Bruno Banani'). But at the moment my algorithm is better when brand name contains special characters.